# Rules: save a node but not "fire" a rule that create a loop

Tags: rules

I have a rule that "fire" on a condition of "node save". Now in the action of this rule I get the node that I receive via "arguments" and set/change some values if some other values are foo or bar.

My problem is: how can I save the node without create a loop ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your rule, or the export code?

Comment: just want to know why you're looping...

Comment: I think he's saving a node in the rule and then that triggers the rules again. Adding a solution now.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. I don't understand the looping without more detail.

Comment: Are you using drupal 7 or 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question but this might be beneficial anyway. Not sure if you're using saving or updating and what you mean by arguments.

You need a Boolean field in your content type that you set to true in the actions of your rule. Then add a condition that if the Boolean is true, the rule doesn't fire repeatably.

You could also skip the extra field and add a condition that one of the fields you set is empty.

If you can't access the fields, you need to add an "entity has field" condition.

Comment: Edited. I got the condition slightly wrong. If it doesn't work, I'd recommend adding some more detail to the question.

Comment: Hey Niall, are you familiar with the "issue" I described in my answer? And how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using hook_node_presave().

Do your changes before node save.

for example, here is a PHP snippet that should do what you want:

```
<?php

function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  $val = arg(1); // if your url is like http://example.com/foo
  if ($val == 'foo') {
     do_something();
  }
}

?>
```

Hope this will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: node_presave is not rules based. I want (if possible) use a rule based solution. but however thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, may i know why you are using rules.?

Comment: i'm want to use rules because the module is used for other reason in the project so I want to have only one point where ALL node operations are.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [issue # 430274](https://www.drupal.org/node/430274), which somehow explains that "after saving something" actually happens ... "before saving something" (which is not a bug, simply how the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module works ...).
From the limited details provided in the question, it could well be that this also explains what causes your loop.

A possible compromise to avoid these kind of issues, is to transform what you're trying to do in your Rules Action (related to *Set a data value*) in a Rules Component, so that your Rule "schedules the execution" (using the Rules Scheduler submodule) of that Rules Component. For example after only a few seconds or minutes later on (if your cron job runs frequent enough, otherwise it'll be next time cron runs). This compromise will ensure that, at the time the Rules Component is executed, the "Save of the node" for sure completed, and your node will have been updated as expected.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.